# Can`t print SimpleXML Element

Tags: php, simplexml

Have code like this:

```
if (file_exists('my.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('my.xml');
    if($xml === NULL)
        echo('ERR NULL $xml</br>');
    else{
        echo('> my.xml opened</br>');   
        print_r($xml);
    }
}

foreach($xml->data->record as $records){
    echo $records->data_to_retrive, PHP_EOL;
}
echo('> Ended</br');
```

Now, the output look like this:

```
> my.xml opened
> Ended
```

So whats wrong with that? Why it don`t show data_to_retrive, and print_r($xml) don`t work? I stuck here, and almost got headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = fopen('my.xml','r');
$prexml = fread($file, filesize('my.xml'));
$prexml = preg_replace('#<([0-9]+)>#si','<z$1>',$prexml);
$prexml = preg_replace('#</([0-9]+)>#si','</z$1>',$prexml);
echo('> File opened</br>');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($prexml);
```

Okay, I repaired my.xml that way, and its working now. Thanks Young for an idea!

Answer (score 0):

[**simplexml_load_file**](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.simplexml-load-file.php) returns `false` if it fails.So you may not use `===` to compare the return value with `NULL` because `false === NULL` will fail.You can use

```
if($xml === false)
```

instead.

Comment: Okay. Now I got on my output 'ERR NULL $xml', so I guess that in $xml is just nothing. Do I think right? So why this happens? Have to chech if I have remote file enabled..

Comment: @KrisyKris  you may check the `my.xml` is  well-formed.

Comment: I think, that was the issue (didnt pass the validation), will do it tomorow, becouse my.xml have about 30,000 lines and give you the answer.

Comment: Okay, I checked this. My xml structure looks like this:

`<data> [root]
 <record>
  ...
  <photo>
   <1>true</1>
   <2>true</2>
  </photo>
  ...
 </record>
</data>`

It looks that in photo <1> is invalid. Do you know why?